# Subdomain url rewriting using htaccess on codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, subdomain

I know this has been asked several times on here, but somehow I can't get any of the code I find to work. My problem is the following.

My url structure looks like this :

`http://www.domain.com/algerie/contact`

`http://www.domain.com/tunisie/demande_devis`

`http://www.domain.com/tunisie/contact`

I would like the url to look like this :

`http://www.algerie.domain.com/contact`

`http://www.tunisie.domain.com/demande_devis`

`http://www.tunisie.domain.com/contact`

I was able to make this work but only using redirections [R], but, I don't what any [R] redirections. Any idea on how to make this work ?

Answer (score 2):

How about this rewrite the url

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi dianuj. This does indeed work, it does however trigger an external redirection. I'm looking for a way to make this work using an internal redirection.